# R Shiny application to import multiple files using a for loop

Tags: r, shiny, import

I am looking into building an R Shiny web application to analyse cyclic voltammetry and UV-Vis data. The raw data should be imported to the Shiny app and subsequently plotted. I want to display multiple data sets in a single plot. I used a for loop to import the single raw data files, but no matter what I change the plot only displays one single dataset. I decided to use a for loop, because at a later stage I want to implement a peak picking algroithm, which is easier to handle on each dataset seperatly.

Here is my server function

```
# Define server logic to read selected files ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Define reactive variable for combined dataframe
  combined_df <- reactive({
    # initialize empty list to store data frames
    dfs <- list()
    files <- list.files(input$files$datapath)
    
    # loop over each selected file and read the data
    for (i in length(input)) {
      
      # extract the file name without the extension
      name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(files[i],)
      # extract the first integer in the file name using regular expression
      df_name <- gsub("\\ .*","", name)
      #read single file
      df <- read.csv(input$files$datapath[i],
                     sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote)
      
      dfs[[df_name]] <- df
    }
    

    # concatenate the data frames into a single data frame
    combined_df <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, dfs, sample = names(dfs)))

    
    
    
    if (!isTruthy(input$text1)) {
      names(combined_df) <- c( "E", "I", "cycle", "Q")
    } else {
      names(combined_df) <- c(input$text1,
                              input$text2,
                              input$text3,
                              input$text4,
                              input$text5)
    }
    #select scans
    combined_df <- combined_df[combined_df$cycle == input$"num1", ]
    combined_df
  })
  combined_df
  output$table <- renderTable({input$files$name})
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # display the first few rows of the combined dataframe
    req(input$files)
    req(combined_df())
    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(combined_df()))
    }
    else {
      return(combined_df())
    }
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    # plot the combined dataframe
    req(input$files)
    req(combined_df())
    ggplot(combined_df(), aes(x = E, y = I)) + geom_path() + theme_article()
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and here my UI function

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
pacman::p_load(pacman, dplyr, GGally, ggplot2, ggthemes, 
               ggvis, httr, lubridate, plotly, rio, rmarkdown, shiny, 
               stringr, tidyr, IDPmisc, tidyverse, miceadds, ggpmisc, latex2exp, viridis,
               GCalignR,fftw,tuneR, gsignal, NbClust, cluster, hopkins, clustertend, factoextra,
               egg, OrgMassSpecR, latex2exp, sjmisc,baseline, gridExtra) 

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("journal"),
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Lab Helper"),
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("CV Scan Rate Plotter",
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
      

      
      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      
      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = "\t"),
      
      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),
      
      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head"),
      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),
      
      numericInput(
        "num1",
        "Select Scan Number",
        2,
        min = 1,
        max = 100,
        step = 1,
        width = NULL
      ),
      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),
      textInput("text1", "Column Name A:", "", placeholder = "E"),
      textInput("text2", "Column Name B:", "", placeholder = "I"),
      textInput("text3", "Column Name C:", "", placeholder = "cycle"),
      textInput("text4", "Column Name D:", "", placeholder = "Q"),
      textInput("text5", "Column Name E:", "", placeholder = "scan"),
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # Input: Select one or more files ----
      fileInput("files", "Choose Files",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
       tableOutput("table"),
      
      # Horizontal line ----

      tags$hr(),
      
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents"),
     
      plotOutput("plot")
      
      
    )
    
  )
),

tabPanel("UV Vis Plotter"),
tabPanel("About"),

),

)
```

Any feedback would be highly appreciated

[This is my output i get from the server function, displayed in the Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op4CG.png)
[But the output should look like this with multiple datasets in one single plot (disregarding the different colour and style elements here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQf5f.png)

Comment: Are all 35 dependencies in your UI really necessary? It's best to make your example as minimal as possible to reproduce the error. It's very hard to help since we don't have any test files to upload and test with. You seem to combine all the files into a single data.frame with `do.call(rbind, ...)`. And you have a single call to `ggplot` in your `renderPlot`. I'm not sure why you would expect multiple plots or what exactly you want to have in each of those plots.

Comment: Should the for loop have a `1:` before `length`: `(i in 1:length(input))`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No the dependecies are not strictly necessary, most of them are just for testing. Regarding your other point, I appended some clarifiying plots on how my output plot looks and waht output i want (with multiple datasets displayed in a single plot).

Comment: Reagrding the loop i tried it also by adding `1:` to the code, although this didnt seem to change the output.

Comment: There are several problems in your code.  First, as @tauft has pointed out, you need a `1:` in your `for` loop, but it should be `for (i in 1:length(files)`, not `for i in 1:length(input)`.  Also, you define `combined_df` as a reactive and then *immediately* overwrite it with `combined_df <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, dfs, sample = names(dfs)))`!  Your example is also not reproducibe as we don't have access to your source files.  Voting to close as not reproducible: there are just too many issues with your code.